# "conda activate" in .bash_profile adds error message with unknown consequences

Tags: bash, macos, unix, anaconda

When I open a terminal window in my Mac OS (now using Catalina but was getting the same behavior before the upgrade) I get the following message three times:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 23 11:38:00 on ttys001
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

The `.bash_profile` file has the following content:

```
conda activate
conda activate
conda activate
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I suspect `conda activate` appears three times because I've installed anaconda three times. In any case, if I delete these three lines and open a new terminal window it does not complain. Can anyone explain this behavior and tell me the pros and cons of deleting these three lines? Shall I delete the whole contents of the file (i.e. the other 16 lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of code managed by `conda init` is standard and should handle activating Conda for you, assuming `auto_activate_base` is set to `true`, which is the default (you can check with `conda config --show auto_activate_base`). I recommend removing the three `conda activate` lines, since they are not necessary, and in my experience are not standard.

While I have seen that error message before by users attempting to run `pip install conda`, I don't really know why you are seeing it in this context. On my system, trying to reference `conda` before the `conda init` section results in a `command not found` error. Perhaps you are adding the Conda `bin/` directory to the `PATH` manually, which has been discouraged since Conda v4.4 (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try `pip install conda`. So that may be what introduced the lines in the file. I now tried again to see if I could reproduce the behavior but it did not happen... I'm not manually adding to `PATH` anything. However, now my computing environment is different: when the lines appeared I had a different OS and Conda had stopped working...

Comment: @BrianBarcelona thanks for the feedback. I'm going to leave that comment about `PATH` in the answer even though it doesn't apply to you, just in case it might pertain to others visiting this question.

Comment: Sounds perfect. I did find quite informative the Release Notes you mentioned (https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0).